# Does Libgdx stage draw include sprites outside the visible area?

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

Does the Libgdx stage `draw` method render everything or only what is seen by viewport and camera? I have many sprites outside the visible area and I wanted to know if I should implement my own algorithm to render only the camera view.

Comment: You question is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547391/libgdx-view-frustum-culling-inside-actor-draw

Comment: You can also have a look at this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699101/proper-using-of-scene2ds-stage-in-a-game-with-a-huge-world